# Потерялся composer.json (yii2) что делать?

Tags: yii2, composer

Помогите, пришел на проект, а там vendor :) на битбакете и нет composer.json, что делать, как решить проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Доброе утро.
В директории vendor/composer должен быть файл installed.json.
Попробуйте там найти информацию о нужных Вам пакетах.

Comment: спасибо! тоже вариант